# Rules ignored when restore quality profile in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, profile

I saw many posts with this question, but I didn't find the answer so I ask. I upgraded Sonarqube from 4.5 to 5.6 and it works fine, but the quality profiles are empty. I tried to restore one with the backup/restore option but the rules are ignored: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOA6p.png). Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you started up your new instance without the code analyzers.

Unfortunately, installing the analyzers now won't restore your profile customizations. You allude to having backup profile files, so you may be able to get them back that way, but you should be aware that you'll [lose some rule customizations](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5366).

Assuming you backed up your database before the upgrade [like the docs tell you to](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading), your best bet is to restore your DB backup to the pre-upgrade state, install the missing code analyzers, *then* run the database upgrade.

Comment: Effectively, my problem comes from the plugins, I added the missing ones and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue with SonarQube 6.4. I was trying to Reload findbugs rules whereas the plugin was not installed. I first installed the plugin for findbug from Admin login - Update screen. After this if we use Create - Reload Profiles option, it works fine.